# Reorder sets of 3D points to retrieve line segments coordinates

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I have the following two sets of 3D points representing lines coordinates and points.
:

```
pts  = {{0., -0.004, 0.}, {0., 0.016, 0.}, {0.001, 0.017, 0.}, {0.006, 0.017, 0.},
        {0.011, 0.017, 0.}, {0.011, 0.021, 0.}, {0.011, 0.022, 0.001}, {0.011, 0.022, 0.015}}
pts1 = {{-0.01, 0.015, 0.}, {-0.01, 0.015, 0.01}, {0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.015, 0.}};
```

In order to export those sets of data into another software, I would need to find the different lines segments creating the "big line".

So far I've only found the following code giving me the correct points order, which is not robust enough since it doesn't work with the `pts1` set.

```
ordered[p_] := p[[Last[FindShortestTour[p, Method -> "AllTours"]]]]
ordered@pts
Graphics3D[{Red, Line@%, Point@pts}]
```

[image: pts]

For the `pts1` I get the following image:

[image: pts1]

I've tried changing the `Method` without any luck.

Unfortunately, I haven't use *Mathematica* in a very long time, and apparently the few skills I had have vanished.

Comment: I'm not sure but this can help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: The problem in the second case is caused by the `DeleteDuplicates`: You only apply it to the input of `FindShortestTour`, but when processing the output, (i.e. `pts[[…]]`, you don't use it. Since `pts1` has duplicates, you get the problem you're seeing.

Comment: The problem is that `FindShortestTour` returns a list of indices w.r.t. its argument (`{1,4,3,2,1}` for `pts1`). If you now use this list to extract points from `pts1` without `DeleteDuplicates`, you get meaningless results. The reason why `pts` doesn't make problems is that the duplicates are all at the end, so the indices of the other elements are not affected

Comment: What version are you using? For me in 11.3 the default method of `FindShortestTour` yields accurate results.

Comment: That might explains why it works with Graphs as well. I'm still on v8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** A more robust approach (than `NearestNeighborGraph` in the original answer below) is to use [`DistanceMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceMatrix.html) to identify the farthest apart pair of points and use one of the two points as the first element and sort all the points by their distance to this point:

```
ClearAll[pathF]
pathF = Module[{max = Max@DistanceMatrix[#] , first},
    first = First @ SelectFirst[Subsets[#, {2}], EuclideanDistance @@ # == max &];
    SortBy[#, EuclideanDistance [#, first] &]] &;

Row[Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ #, Blue, 
   Line @ pathF @ #}, BoxRatios -> 1, ImageSize -> 300] & /@ {pts,  pts1}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

An alternative is to use `NearestNeighborGraph` and `FindPath`:

```
pathF = Module[{nng = NearestNeighborGraph@#, l = Length@#}, 
    FindPath[nng, ## & @@ GraphPeriphery[nng], l]] &;

paths = pathF /@ {pts, pts1};
Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Line@#, Blue, Sphere[#, .5]}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, Boxed -> True] & /@ paths // Row
```

[image]

```
paths2 = pathF /@ {RandomSample @ pts, RandomSample @ pts1}
Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Line@#, Blue, Sphere[#, .5]}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, Boxed -> True] & /@ paths // Row
```

> same picture